# Cortex-M33 MTB configuration - When MTB buffer is full

Tags: arm, embedded, trace, cortex-m, trustzone

I am exploring the MTB feature on Cortex-M hardware and doing experiments on Arm mps2+ FPGA board with the Cortex-m33 image, which enables the TrustZone technique. From what I learned, the MTB can be configured to record non-sequential branches of the execution. The record will be written directly to the allocated SRAM by the MTB unit automatically. During the experiment, I have several questions.

1. When the MTB buffer is full, there are two ways to handle it. One way is to rewrite the buffer from the very beginning. Another way is to set a watermark, which will let the PE enter the Debug State. I checked the document that the Debug State means we need an external debugger or another core to handle. Since the board I use is single-core and I prefer not to use the external debugger, is there another way to notify the CPU without halting it when the MTB buffer is full?
2. Based on the first question, I had several trials:

- I configured the DWT comparator to monitor the data address write,
  but it seems DWT cannot monitor hardware writing like MTB does.
- I configured Non-secure MPU to set the MTB buffer region as RO, but it still cannot trigger a secure fault. I checked the document `ARM CoreSight MTB-M33 page A2-26: The MTB-M33 ensures that trace write accesses have priority over AHB accesses`. Is that the reason why the
  MPU can not constrain MTB writing?
- I also configured SAU to set the MTB buffer as secure, it still cannot trigger the secure fault when non-secure trace writing happens.
- Then I went back to read the MTB document. MTB actually has the MTB_SECURE register that can partition the MTB buffer as secure or non-secure. But I don't know is that because the board or the image I use does not fully implement the MTB, I cannot modify the MTB_SECURE register except for the last two bits.

So at last, **is there another way to notify the CPU without halting it when the MTB buffer is full**? Like what Intel Processor Trace does, which will generate an interrupt.

I hope I describe the question clearly and I very appreciate if someone could give me any suggestion. Thank you so much!